# Firebase -'isDirectChannelEstablished' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs channel for downstream message delivery

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just uploaded my Firebase pods and got this warning message:

> 'isDirectChannelEstablished' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is
>   deprecated, please use APNs channel for downstream message delivery

Warning appears here:

```
Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
```

How can I remove this warning?

Comment: What are you doing that requires this option to be enabled?

Comment: I added it so long ago I actually forgot but I receive remote notifications so it must've had something to do with it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you should just remove that line.  According to the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessaging#shouldestablishdirectchannel):

> When set to YES, Firebase Messaging will automatically establish a
>   socket-based, direct channel to the FCM server. Enable this only if
>   you are sending upstream messages or receiving non-APNS, data-only
>   messages in foregrounded apps. Default is NO.

So, unless your app is doing either of the things described here, it's not necessary.  According to the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#fcm):

> Deprecated FCM direct channel messaging via
>   shouldEstablishDirectChannel. Instead, use APNs for downstream message
>   delivery. Add content_available key to your payload if you want to
>   continue use legacy APIs, but we strongly recommend HTTP v1 API as it
>   provides full APNs support. The deprecated API will be removed in
>   Firebase 7 (#4710).

Comment: what should I do if I'm using upstream messages?

Answer (score 0):

If you use cordova-plugin-firebasex for data message notifications in ios, and not getting data message properly?

[enter link description here](https://gitlab.walletfactory.com/GitHub/cordova-plugin-firebasex/commit/fa6c2863e9b56f6c3f3d88cd7067da64a2d45b6c#5ab446a9ee40705ee4a205b95c64b54bed1db063)

Change AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.m file like below

```
#import "AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.h"
#import "FirebasePlugin.h"
#import "Firebase.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>


@import UserNotifications;
@import FirebaseFirestore;

// Implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to receive display notification via APNS for devices running iOS 10 and above.
// Implement FIRMessagingDelegate to receive data message via FCM for devices running iOS 10 and above.
@interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate>
@end

#define kApplicationInBackgroundKey @"applicationInBackground"

@implementation AppDelegate (FirebasePlugin)

static AppDelegate* instance;

+ (AppDelegate*) instance {
    return instance;
}

static NSDictionary* mutableUserInfo;
static FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle authStateChangeListener;
static bool authStateChangeListenerInitialized = false;
static bool shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false;

+ (void)load {
    Method original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:));
    Method swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(application:swizzledDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

- (void)setApplicationInBackground:(NSNumber *)applicationInBackground {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kApplicationInBackgroundKey, applicationInBackground, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSNumber *)applicationInBackground {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kApplicationInBackgroundKey);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application swizzledDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self application:application swizzledDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    
    @try{
        instance = self;
        
        bool isFirebaseInitializedWithPlist = false;
        if(![FIRApp defaultApp]) {
            // get GoogleService-Info.plist file path
            NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist"];
            
            // if file is successfully found, use it
            if(filePath){
                [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:@"GoogleService-Info.plist found, setup: [FIRApp configureWithOptions]"];
                // create firebase configure options passing .plist as content
                FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

                // configure FIRApp with options
                [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
                
                isFirebaseInitializedWithPlist = true;
            }else{
                // no .plist found, try default App
                [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logError:@"GoogleService-Info.plist NOT FOUND, setup: [FIRApp defaultApp]"];
                [FIRApp configure];
            }
        }else{
            // Firebase SDK has already been initialised:
            // Assume that another call (probably from another plugin) did so with the plist
            isFirebaseInitializedWithPlist = true;
        }
        
      
        
        shouldEstablishDirectChannel = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"shouldEstablishDirectChannel"] boolValue];

        // Set FCM messaging delegate
        [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
        [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
        
        // Setup Firestore
        [FirebasePlugin setFirestore:[FIRFirestore firestore]];
        
        // Setup Google SignIn
        [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = [FIRApp defaultApp].options.clientID;
        [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
        
        authStateChangeListener = [[FIRAuth auth] addAuthStateDidChangeListener:^(FIRAuth * _Nonnull auth, FIRUser * _Nullable user) {
            @try {
                if(!authStateChangeListenerInitialized){
                    authStateChangeListenerInitialized = true;
                }else{
                    [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin executeGlobalJavascript:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FirebasePlugin._onAuthStateChange(%@)", (user != nil ? @"true": @"false")]];
                }
            }@catch (NSException *exception) {
                [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin handlePluginExceptionWithoutContext:exception];
            }
        }];

        // Set NSNotificationCenter observer
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                     name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

        self.applicationInBackground = @(YES);
        
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin handlePluginExceptionWithoutContext:exception];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.applicationInBackground = @(NO);
    [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
    [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enter foreground: FCM direct channel = %@", shouldEstablishDirectChannel ? @"true" : @"false"]];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.applicationInBackground = @(YES);
    [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
    [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:@"Enter background: FCM direct channel = false"];
}

# pragma mark - Google SignIn
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
    @try{
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult;
        if (error == nil) {
            GIDAuthentication *authentication = user.authentication;
            FIRAuthCredential *credential =
            [FIRGoogleAuthProvider credentialWithIDToken:authentication.idToken
                                           accessToken:authentication.accessToken];
            
            NSNumber* key = [[FirebasePlugin firebasePlugin] saveAuthCredential:credential];
            NSMutableDictionary* result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [result setValue:@"true" forKey:@"instantVerification"];
            [result setValue:key forKey:@"id"];
            pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:result];
        } else {
          pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:error.description];
        }
        if ([FirebasePlugin firebasePlugin].googleSignInCallbackId != nil) {
            [[FirebasePlugin firebasePlugin].commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:[FirebasePlugin firebasePlugin].googleSignInCallbackId];
        }
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin handlePluginExceptionWithoutContext:exception];
    }
}

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didDisconnectWithUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString* msg = @"Google SignIn delegate: didDisconnectWithUser";
    if(error != nil){
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", msg, error]];
    }else{
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:msg];
    }
}

# pragma mark - FIRMessagingDelegate
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken {
    [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didReceiveRegistrationToken: %@", fcmToken]];
    @try{
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin sendToken:fcmToken];
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin handlePluginExceptionWithoutContext:exception];
    }
}

- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    @try{
        [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] instanceIDWithHandler:^(FIRInstanceIDResult * _Nullable result,
                                                            NSError * _Nullable error) {
            @try{
                if (error == nil) {
                    NSString *refreshedToken = result.token;
                    [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tokenRefreshNotification: %@", refreshedToken]];
                    [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin sendToken:refreshedToken];
                }else{
                    [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tokenRefreshNotification: %@", error.description]];
                }
            }@catch (NSException *exception) {
                [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin handlePluginExceptionWithoutContext:exception];
            }
        }];
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin handlePluginExceptionWithoutContext:exception];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;
    [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: %@", deviceToken]];
    [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin sendApnsToken:[FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin hexadecimalStringFromData:deviceToken]];
    
    // Set UNUserNotificationCenter delegate
    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
}

//Tells the app that a remote notification arrived that indicates there is data to be fetched.
// Called when a message arrives in the foreground and remote notifications permission has been granted
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    @try{
        [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
        mutableUserInfo = [userInfo mutableCopy];
        NSDictionary* aps = [mutableUserInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
        bool isContentAvailable = false;
        if([aps objectForKey:@"alert"] != nil){
            isContentAvailable = [[aps objectForKey:@"content-available"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
            [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"notification" forKey:@"messageType"];
            NSString* tap;
            if([self.applicationInBackground isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]] && !isContentAvailable){
                tap = @"background";
            }
            [mutableUserInfo setValue:tap forKey:@"tap"];
        }else{
            [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"data" forKey:@"messageType"];
        }

        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didReceiveRemoteNotification: %@", mutableUserInfo]];
        
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
        if([self.applicationInBackground isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]] && isContentAvailable){
            [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logError:@"didReceiveRemoteNotification: omitting foreground notification as content-available:1 so system notification will be shown"];
        }else{
            [self processMessageForForegroundNotification:mutableUserInfo];
        }
        if([self.applicationInBackground isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]] || !isContentAvailable){
            [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin sendNotification:mutableUserInfo];
        }
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin handlePluginExceptionWithoutContext:exception];
    }
}

// Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
// Called when a data message is arrives in the foreground and remote notifications permission has been NOT been granted
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    @try{
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didReceiveMessage: %@", remoteMessage.appData]];
        
        NSDictionary* appData = [remoteMessage.appData mutableCopy];
        [appData setValue:@"data" forKey:@"messageType"];
        [self processMessageForForegroundNotification:appData];
     
        // This will allow us to handle FCM data-only push messages even if the permission for push
        // notifications is yet missing. This will only work when the app is in the foreground.
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin sendNotification:appData];
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin handlePluginExceptionWithoutContext:exception];
    }
}

// Scans a message for keys which indicate a notification should be shown.
// If found, extracts relevant keys and uses then to display a local notification
-(void)processMessageForForegroundNotification:(NSDictionary*)messageData {
    bool showForegroundNotification = [messageData objectForKey:@"notification_foreground"];
    if(!showForegroundNotification){
        return;
    }
    
    NSString* title = nil;
    NSString* body = nil;
    NSString* sound = nil;
    NSNumber* badge = nil;
    
    // Extract APNS notification keys
    NSDictionary* aps = [messageData objectForKey:@"aps"];
    if([aps objectForKey:@"alert"] != nil){
        NSDictionary* alert = [aps objectForKey:@"alert"];
        if([alert objectForKey:@"title"] != nil){
            title = [alert objectForKey:@"title"];
        }
        if([alert objectForKey:@"body"] != nil){
            body = [alert objectForKey:@"body"];
        }
        if([aps objectForKey:@"sound"] != nil){
            sound = [aps objectForKey:@"sound"];
        }
        if([aps objectForKey:@"badge"] != nil){
            badge = [aps objectForKey:@"badge"];
        }
    }
    
    // Extract data notification keys
    if([messageData objectForKey:@"notification_title"] != nil){
        title = [messageData objectForKey:@"notification_title"];
    }
    if([messageData objectForKey:@"notification_body"] != nil){
        body = [messageData objectForKey:@"notification_body"];
    }
    if([messageData objectForKey:@"notification_ios_sound"] != nil){
        sound = [messageData objectForKey:@"notification_ios_sound"];
    }
    if([messageData objectForKey:@"notification_ios_badge"] != nil){
        badge = [messageData objectForKey:@"notification_ios_badge"];
    }
   
    if(title == nil || body == nil){
        return;
    }
    
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
        @try{
            if (settings.alertSetting == UNNotificationSettingEnabled) {
                UNMutableNotificationContent *objNotificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
                objNotificationContent.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:title arguments:nil];
                objNotificationContent.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:body arguments:nil];
                
                NSDictionary* alert = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       title, @"title",
                                       body, @"body"
                                       , nil];
                NSMutableDictionary* aps = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     alert, @"alert",
                                     nil];
                
                if(![sound isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] || [sound isEqualToString:@"default"]){
                    objNotificationContent.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
                    [aps setValue:sound forKey:@"sound"];
                }else if(sound != nil){
                    objNotificationContent.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:sound];
                    [aps setValue:sound forKey:@"sound"];
                }
                
                if(badge != nil){
                    [aps setValue:badge forKey:@"badge"];
                }
                
                NSString* messageType = @"data";
                if([mutableUserInfo objectForKey:@"messageType"] != nil){
                    messageType = [mutableUserInfo objectForKey:@"messageType"];
                }
                
                NSDictionary* userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          @"true", @"notification_foreground",
                                          messageType, @"messageType",
                                          aps, @"aps"
                                          , nil];
                
                objNotificationContent.userInfo = userInfo;
                
                UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger =  [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:0.1f repeats:NO];
                UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"local_notification" content:objNotificationContent trigger:trigger];
                [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:@"Local Notification succeeded"];
                    } else {
                        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Local Notification failed: %@", error.description]];
                    }
                }];
            }else{
                [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logError:@"processMessageForForegroundNotification: cannot show notification as permission denied"];
            }
        }@catch (NSException *exception) {
            [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin handlePluginExceptionWithoutContext:exception];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error.description]];
}

// Asks the delegate how to handle a notification that arrived while the app was running in the foreground
// Called when an APS notification arrives when app is in foreground
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
    
    @try{

        if (![notification.request.trigger isKindOfClass:UNPushNotificationTrigger.class] && ![notification.request.trigger isKindOfClass:UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.class]){
            [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logError:@"willPresentNotification: aborting as not a supported UNNotificationTrigger"];
            return;
        }
        
        [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:notification.request.content.userInfo];
        
        mutableUserInfo = [notification.request.content.userInfo mutableCopy];
        
        NSString* messageType = [mutableUserInfo objectForKey:@"messageType"];
        if(![messageType isEqualToString:@"data"]){
            [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"notification" forKey:@"messageType"];
        }

        // Print full message.
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"willPresentNotification: %@", mutableUserInfo]];

        
        NSDictionary* aps = [mutableUserInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
        bool isContentAvailable = [[aps objectForKey:@"content-available"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        if(isContentAvailable){
            [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logError:@"willPresentNotification: aborting as content-available:1 so system notification will be shown"];
            return;
        }
        
        bool showForegroundNotification = [mutableUserInfo objectForKey:@"notification_foreground"];
        bool hasAlert = [aps objectForKey:@"alert"] != nil;
        bool hasBadge = [aps objectForKey:@"badge"] != nil;
        bool hasSound = [aps objectForKey:@"sound"] != nil;

        if(showForegroundNotification){
            [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"willPresentNotification: foreground notification alert=%@, badge=%@, sound=%@", hasAlert ? @"YES" : @"NO", hasBadge ? @"YES" : @"NO", hasSound ? @"YES" : @"NO"]];
            if(hasAlert && hasBadge && hasSound){
                completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert + UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge + UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);
            }else if(hasAlert && hasBadge){
                completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert + UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
            }else if(hasAlert && hasSound){
                completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert + UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);
            }else if(hasBadge && hasSound){
                completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge + UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);
            }else if(hasAlert){
                completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
            }else if(hasBadge){
                completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
            }else if(hasSound){
                completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);
            }
        }else{
            [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:@"willPresentNotification: foreground notification not set"];
        }
        
        if(![messageType isEqualToString:@"data"]){
            [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin sendNotification:mutableUserInfo];
        }
        
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin handlePluginExceptionWithoutContext:exception];
    }
}

// Asks the delegate to process the user's response to a delivered notification.
// Called when user taps on system notification
- (void) userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
 didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
          withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
    @try{
        
        if (![response.notification.request.trigger isKindOfClass:UNPushNotificationTrigger.class] && ![response.notification.request.trigger isKindOfClass:UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.class]){
            [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logMessage:@"didReceiveNotificationResponse: aborting as not a supported UNNotificationTrigger"];
            return;
        }

        [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:response.notification.request.content.userInfo];
        
        mutableUserInfo = [response.notification.request.content.userInfo mutableCopy];
        
        NSString* tap;
        if([self.applicationInBackground isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]){
            tap = @"background";
        }else{
            tap = @"foreground";
            
        }
        [mutableUserInfo setValue:tap forKey:@"tap"];
        if([mutableUserInfo objectForKey:@"messageType"] == nil){
            [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"notification" forKey:@"messageType"];
        }
        
        // Dynamic Actions
        if (response.actionIdentifier && ![response.actionIdentifier isEqual:UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier]) {
            [mutableUserInfo setValue:response.actionIdentifier forKey:@"action"];
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logInfo:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didReceiveNotificationResponse: %@", mutableUserInfo]];

        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin sendNotification:mutableUserInfo];

        completionHandler();
        
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin handlePluginExceptionWithoutContext:exception];
    }
}

// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    // Print full message
    [FirebasePlugin.firebasePlugin _logInfo:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"applicationReceivedRemoteMessage: %@", [remoteMessage appData]]];
}






@end**
```